# dd to ISO from disc drive makes unmountable / unburnable image?

Tags: command-line, disk-utility

I'm trying to `dd` from a disc in my DVD drive on my MacBook to an `ISO`, but the image always ends up as unmountable and unburnable. The disc is unmounted when I start the process.

I've used `dd` many times before - in OSX and in various Linux distros - without any problems. Am I doing something wrong?

The syntax I'm using is `dd if=/dev/disk1 of=~/Desktop/image.iso`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With CDs and DVDs on Mac OS X, the /dev/diskN entry seems to be the raw disc contents (i.e. it includes things like media error correction data).  For imaging, you want /dev/diskNs0 (or sometimes /dev/diskNs1 etc, especially on a multisession disc).  If the disc has a partition table, the mountable volumes will actually be e.g. /dev/diskNs1s2.

BTW, you can also create iso-style images from the GUI with Disk Utility: select the session from Disk Utility's sidebar (note: the session will be the item directly under the disc drive in the sidebar; if the disc has a partition table, there volume will be listed separately under that, and it's not what you want), then go to the menu and select File > New > Image from .  Then, select CD/DVD Master for the image format.  It'l name the image with a .cdr extension, but the format is the same as a typical .iso image.

Answer (score 0):

In this case you can take one of two approached.

Use ccd2iso to convert the dd iso. This will give you the results you are looking for.

ccd2iso is not built into Mac OS but it can be installed using homebrew.

The command would look like this:

```
ccd2iso inputfile.iso outputfile.iso
```

---

Alternatively

Insert your optical disc.

After it has mounted enter the following in your terminal window:

```
diskutil info /dev/diskN | grep "Block Size"
```

Note: The N in diskN represents the disk number assigned for the disk you inserted but what is important here is that you will get the block size of the CD/DVD for use in the next command.

The path of the optical disk drive being used can be found by typing `drutil status` into terminal.

The next command would be (you might not need sudo if you detached the disk using the DiskUtility GUI or otherwise):

```
sudo dd if=/dev/diskNs0 of=my_disc.iso bs=2352
```

Notice: The slice is included and this will yeild a disc image that mounts as you most likely experienced in the Linux platform.

The method described above was tested against a random disc and an md5 was calculated against the iso. That md5 was compared to the md5 calculated against the iso image of 3 other tools, Burn (GUI app), AnyToIso (free GUI app), and ddrescue using the the following command `ddrescue -b 2352 -r4 -v /dev/diskNs0 ddrescue.iso log.txt` and the all md5 results were precisely the same.

Reference: http://www.digitizationguidelines.gov/audio-visual/documents/Preserve_DVDs_BloodReport_20140901.pdf see page 9 for more on `dd`

The reference does not suggest using the slice number (diskN**s0**) when the intended goal is an archival disc image. Without the slice number and block size specified I have found that an unmountable disc image results in Mac OS X but after converting the disc image using ccd2iso a mountable disc image does result and traversal of the directory is possible.